# Orientation change: reloading layouts from resources

Tags: android, layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to adapt my app for tablets with `large` and `xlarge` screens (Android 3.0+ or API level 11+). Therefore, I created two folders: `res/layout-large-port-v11` and `res/layout-large-land-v11`. When I first rotate my tablet and then launch the app, everything works well, but when I rotate the tablet while my app is working, Android stretches and rotates old layout, but doesn't load the proper one (proper for new orientation). What's wrong?

My tablet is Acer Iconia A500 (Honeycomb 3.2, API level 13)

You can see [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/o2genum/HowToSay/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) and all code in the [app's repo on github](https://github.com/o2genum/HowToSay). `DashboardActivity` contains all logic for tablets.

P.S.: Everithing still works pretty well on my Android 2.2 phone with `normal` screen. Maybe something wrong with qualifiers? Maybe I should also create `-v12, -v13 -v14` and `-xlarge` duplicates of the two folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing `orientation` from `configChanges`? With this declaration, you are overriding the default behaviour of Android when changing orientation - this may (or may not) lead to problems like the one you described.

Comment: Thanks. Right. I forgot I overrided that behaviour and now I must reload all layouts in `onConfigurationChanged()` by myself.